# Plotting in QGIS too slow. How to make it faster?

Tags: qgis, layouts

Layout plotting for printing in QGIS, when files have thousands of polygons, is blocking at every small move I make or any change in the caption. Im am using QGIS 3.30.3 with a very fast computer (i7, 32gb RAM, graphic card with 8gb RTX3070) so it should not be this problem of hardware or software.

Is there an option that the map is not rendering completely at every move so I can edit the layout without blocking? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: You can turn rendering off in the map settings panel.

Comment: See https://twitter.com/nyalldawson/status/1669055062629564417?s=20

Comment: Thank you but I cannot find the map settings panel. I have looked everywhere. Can you explain better? Thanks.